# From this error, how to understand np.arrays in python?

Tags: python, fortran

Suppose I have two numpy arrays:

```
a = np.zeros(N, N, N)
b = np.zeros(N+1, N+1, N+1)
```

Then I want to broadcast 'a' to 'b', which is simply if I use (1)

```
for k1 in range(N):
    for k2 in range(N):
        for k3 in range(N):
            b[k1][k2][k3] = a[k1][k2][k3]
```

This works well. But I want to make it simpler and faster, so I use (2)

```
b[0:N][0:N][0:N] = a[0:N][0:N][0:N]
```

Then error occurs ( if I set N = 10 ):

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,10,10) into shape (10,11,11)

OK, it is solved from [Why does indexing numpy arrays with brackets and commas differ in behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113994/why-does-indexing-numpy-arrays-with-brackets-and-commas-differ-in-behavior)

Comment: `b[0:N,0:N,:N] = a[0:N,0:N,0:N]`

Comment: @anishtain4  So this means when I want to access an single element of an ndarry, I'd better always use the commas one?

Comment: Yes, for numpy arrays commas are the rule (except very special cases). The way you have indexed them is used for lists.