# What is x[ : , 0]?

Tags: python, numpy

I don't understand what it does, and only saw it used by a sklearn-object.
On trying some testing like this

```
x = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
y = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]

print(y[:, 0])
```

I got this error (with both x and y):

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

My assumption was that the `:` before the comma tells Python to take all entries, while the `0` specifies which 'subset'.

How does one use this expression properly and what does it do?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a numpy indexing notation. This is not standard python. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113994/why-does-indexing-numpy-arrays-with-brackets-and-commas-differ-in-behavior

Comment: @m00am thank you that one explains it well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38114048/2862719) this is a numpy-specific notation to index arrays, not plain python. This is why it does not work on your code. In your (initial) case, the sklearn object probably wraps a numpy array that supports the numpy slicing syntax.

In your specific case, it would work as follows:

```
import numpy as np

y = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]])
print(y[:, 0])

# prints: [1 2 3]
```

This would yield all indexes along the first axis (i.e. use full column vectors), but use only index 0 in the second axis (i.e. use only the first column vector).

Comment: Just tried the same thing and now it works as expected, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

What you express would work with more complex objects, like numpy (and its famous [slicing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp)). In the case of vanilla Python, this is not possible. To access a specific number (in your case) you would have to do `x[2][1]` (yielding `4` in your example).

To achieve what you want (take the first item of each tuple), you would do
`[item[0] for item in y]`. This is list comprehension: iterate through `y`, take the object at the first index of each item, and make a list out of that.

Comment: I was confused, since native Python also supports some slicing like e.g. `y[ : 2]` produces `[[1, 2],[2, 3]]`.  m00ams reply clears that up. Thank your for your answer though!